# Process Massive Files (> 60GB each) To Replace Lines From One File to Another And Write To New File Python

Tags: python, bigdata

I have two files (both 60GB) and will expect larger files in the future, the goal is to manipulate the first file by merging certain lines together and then going into a new file and seeing if the lines from the second file match part of the lines from the extracted merged lines in the first file, then write the result to a new file.

At first, I was creating a dictionary from the first file - having the keys be the ID and the value be the merged part. Then, I was having the program look in the second file and see if the lines matched the key, then have that line = the key plus the value. Finally, I wrote this all to a new file. This worked for files as big as 30GB each, but now it's being killed. Here is my script:

```
## create dictionary 
readID_dictionary = {}

## open the read 1 fastq file as R1
with open(R1_Path, 'rt') as R1:
    for line in R1:
        if line[0] != '@': continue
        readID = line.split()[0]
        readID_dictionary[readID] = next(R1)[:20]

with open(R2_Path, 'rt') as R2:
    with open(newfile, "w") as newfile:
        for line in R2:
            if line[0] != '@': continue
            readID = line.split()[0]
            if readID in readID_dictionary:
                readID = readID + '_' + readID_dictionary[readID]
            sequence = next(R2)
            blank = next(R2)
            quality = next(R2)

            newfile.write(readID +'\n')
            newfile.write(sequence + blank + quality)
```

Does anybody have any ideas? I'm thinking the dictionary is what is definitely slowing it down and killing it. I tried creating a file with the items in the dictionary and thought I could then search for matching lines between the two files but to no luck.

Here is a sample of the first file that I would be turning into a dictionary (which I believe is causing the memory problem):

@Alex You can use this for the sample for the first file that I would be turning into a dictionary (the main problem I believe as far as memory goes):

```
@id:number:one_FFKF
@id:number:two_KKKK
@id:number:three_NGTG
@id:number:four_IOPL
@id:number:five_YIOK
@id:number:six_OPOP
```

And for the second file in which I would taking each line that starts with "@" seeing if it matches with the lines in the dictionary (or wherever the results from the first file are - even straight from the first file would be best) and if it does match, replace it with the line from the first file and keep the rest from the second file. Finally, write the new results to a new file.

```
@id:number:one
ASKLJDFSJKLF
+
LLLLLLLLLL
@id:number:two
LKSDJF:LSDKFJ
+
LLLJKJKLLLLL
@id:number:eight_NGTG
LSDKJ:FLKSDFJ
@id:number:twenty_IOPL
+
LKJLLLLLKJKLJL
@id:number:eleven_YIOK
LKSJDF:LKSDJF
+
LLKJLKLLLLLLL
@id:number:ten_OPOP
KSJDHFLSKDJFH
+
LKLKLLLLLLLLL
```

Comment: Your script has the memory footprint of an elephant. It is most likely killed because it used up all RAM. You will have to come up with a solution that does not so much data in memory.

Comment: Is it the use of dictionary that uses up so much memory?

Comment: It's not that you use dictionaries. It's the fact that you fill them up with an enormous amount of data.

Comment: So what would you recommend?

Comment: A slow but robust way would be to replace the dictionary with a `shelve`. But as the underlying data structure is a xdbm file, performance could still be *acceptable*. IMHO, it probably deserves a try...

Comment: @IronMan18 Can you add a small sample of the files ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SergeBallesta, I've never used shelve before. Can you provide an example of how I might be able to use it for this purpose?

Comment: @Alex Just added sample text at the end of my question.

Comment: Why do you have files to begin with? Certainly a database would make more sense for this type of action

Comment: @OneCricketeer Because the output has to be in a certain file format.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, if you want to handle a big workload, you will need to split it up somehow. With files, it is somewhat easy: you just need to read it in blocks.

In this example, the function reads the number of lines dictated by the variable `batch` and then runs that data against the entire file and writes the results created, then loops back and grabs the next chunk of lines until there are no more lines.

```
def big_merge_out(in_a, in_b, out, batch=2):
    # Old style of file handling
    file_a = open(in_a, 'r')
    file_b = open(in_b, 'r')
    result = open(out, 'w')

    def next_batch(content):
        content.clear()
        for _ in range(batch):
            a_line_k = file_a.readline()
            a_line_v = file_a.readline()

            if not a_line_k or not a_line_v:
                break
            if a_line_k[0] != '@':
                continue

            # (1) Your read data thing
            key = a_line_k.split()[0]
            content[key] = a_line_v[:20]

        if content:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    data = {}
    while next_batch(data):
        file_b.seek(0, 0)
        while True:
            b_line = file_b.readline()
            if not b_line:
                break
            if b_line[0] != '@':
                continue

            # (2) Your write data thing
            key = b_line.split()[0]
            if key in data:
                key = key + '_' + data[key]
            sequence = next(file_b)
            blank = next(file_b)
            quality = next(file_b)

            result.write(key + '\n')
            result.write(sequence + blank + quality)

    file_a.close()
    file_b.close()
    result.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    big_merge_out('A.txt', 'B.txt', 'D.txt')
```

(Because I could not figure out what the code is supposed to do with the samples you gave, you will have to fix or replace `# (1)` and `# (2)`.)